# Convert QstringList to Qstring in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qstring

I am trying to get a list of filenames using QFileDialog and wanted to be displayed in a QLineEdit (in Python 2.7).

```
self.resLine = QLineEdit()
xxres_file = (QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Select File', '', '*.txt'))
self.resLine.setText(xxres_file)
```

It expects (as the error says) a QString:

```
TypeError: QLineEdit.setText(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QStringList'
```

Could someone help me with converting a QStringList into a QString.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you want is the string in the `QStringList` not the list itself

You can use the QStringList.join method to join the elements in the list together and then call split on it to get a native python list

```
strlist = xxres_file.join(",") # this returns a string of all the elements in the QStringList separated by comma's

strlist = strlist.split(",") # you can optionally split the string to get all the elements in a python list

self.resLine.setText(strlist[0]) # your list contains only one string in this case
```

In python 3 `QStringList` and `QString` are mapped to native python list and strings respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This unfortunately doesn't work when i select multiple files. Using just `strlist = xxres_file.join(",")` and `self.resLine.setText(strlist)` solves the problem with multiple files. Pls correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes you're right...it joins all the elements in the `QStringList` into a single string, seperated by comma's (or by any separator you specify). but if you want the individual elements for some other reason you can just call `.split()` on the string since it's now a python string

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a fairly recent version of pyqt, you can also tell pyqt to use the newer api for qstrings

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)

# Do pyqt imports afterwards
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

Then you just use the regular `str` and `list` methods.